# Calculating acceleration due to gravity using General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, computational-physics, simulations

A few months ago I wrote a program which simulates how user-defined bodies moved under each other's gravities using Newton's Law of Gravitation. For each body, I calculated the total acceleration from all of the other bodies and moved it accordingly.

I would like to see if this can be done using General Relativity. Presumably, I would have to find each body's effect on spacetime and then calculate the body's acceleration/velocity as it moves over the warped spacetime. In the end, I would like to see if I can recreate Mercury's motion around the Sun, as calculated by Einstein.

If there is no single equation or set of equations which can be used to calculate the motion of a particle under gravity, I would love to see an example of where this has already been implemented.

Comment: Just a side note, I have no experience in differential geometry... I imagine that may be problematic

Comment: Okay, so this is not impossible, but you have a tough road ahead of you. Not knowing differential geometry is indeed a problem, since that is essentially the same as not knowing general relativity. And numerical relativity is not simple at all.

Comment: I think one needs density and flows and fluxes and stress prescribed at every point, then solve a PDE system for the metric field at every point. The next step is unclear to me though.

Comment: @Emil Hm I see. I think I'll leave it then. PDEs are out of my knowledge

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems to me that the question I've linked should be what you're looking for. The linked questions in the sidebar of that question may also be of use.